# Как создать или найти такой переход на сайте?

Tags: html, css

Мне очень нужен именно такой переход или похожий. Хочу вставить на свой сайт, уж очень понравился. Это, я так понимаю, просто png, но где найти их или как-то можно самому сделать на каком-нибудь сайте, подскажите, пожалуйста[image: Вот сам переход]

Answer (score 3):

Вариантов несколько:

- Найти в поисковых ресурсах (Google, Yandex, и т.п.)
- Взять напрямую с сайта (исследовать код страницы при помощи инструментов браузера, <kbd>F12</kbd>, например..)
- Создать\передать искомое изображение самостоятельно, в графических редакторах, типо Photoshop, Illustrator и т.п.)
- Ну и самый простой вариант (походу, да), попросить это сделать сообщество **ruSO**.

Ну раз Вы выбрали последний вариант, то держите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!))

Comment: @user13839598, если мой ответ вам помог, то отметьте его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку.